# Reactor Kafka producer- Unable to retry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, reactor-kafka

I have created a KafkaProducer using (reactor.kafka.sender.KafkaSender) using Reactor Kafka (a functional Java API for Kafka). Using the below producer configurations,

```
max.block.ms = 8000
request.timeout.ms= 4000
retries = 3
retry.backoff.ms = 2000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 512
acks = all
```

when i try to publish a record to an invalid topic, I am getting timeout exception

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 8000 ms
```

Which is as expected. But I have configured for retries which are not happening. I am under the assumption that after `max.block.ms` / `request.timeout.ms` has passed out, retry will happen after every `retry.backoff.ms` till `metadata.max.age.ms` or `retries` are exhausted.
FYI, code:

```
    String topic = "order/";
    int count = 1;
    Flux<SenderRecord<String, Event, EventInfo>> source = Flux.range(1, count).map(x -> {
      Event event = new Event();
      return SenderRecord.create(
            new ProducerRecord<String, Event>(topic, event.getX(),
                event), event.getEvent());
    });
    kafkaSender.send(source).subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));
    kafkaSender.close();
```

- are the configurations correct for enabling retry?
- when would the retry happen after `request.timeout.ms`/`max.block.ms`?
- what changes need to be made in above code to allow for retry?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should also set "delivery.timeout.ms"

Refer the documentation here : https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#retries

`Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon receiving the error. Allowing retries without setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1 will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first. Note additionally that produce requests will be failed before the number of retries has been exhausted if the timeout configured by delivery.timeout.ms expires first before successful acknowledgement. Users should generally prefer to leave this config unset and instead use delivery.timeout.ms to control retry behavior.`

Comment: I am using apache kafka version 2.0.0 and it doesn't seem to have this configuration setting that you mentioned.

Comment: I believe it should be there even with kafka version 2.0.0 since documentation doesn't talk about deprecation. Did you give a try?